# Avoid Type Casting During Data Processing

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, casting

I can't seem to figure out the best approach to tackle the following problem. Let's say there is an abstract base class with several concrete subclasses:

```
public abstract class AbstractType { /* common properties */ }

public class TypeA { /* properties of type A */ }
public class TypeB { /* properties of type A */ }`
```

These are domain classes (JPA entities). The properties of the types are (amongst other things) used to validate user data. I'm under the assumption that adding logic to the domain model itself is considered bad practice. Therefore, I want to avoid adding a `validate` method to the concrete subclasses. Like so:

```
UserInput userInput = ...;
AbstractType data = ...;
data.validate(userInput);
```

I don't see an option without having to cast the domain model,
if I want to move the logic to a logic layer. With the limited knowledge I have, I can only come up with following two similar "solutions", using some kind of handler interface.

1. Keep some explicit reference to the handler in the type

   ```
   public interface TypeHandler {
       public validate(AbstractType data, UserInput userInput);
   }

   /* TypeAHandler & TypeBHandler implementations */

   public enum Type {
       TYPE_A(new TypeAHandler()),
       TYPE_B(new TypeBHandler());

       private TypeHandler handler;

       public Handler(TypeHandler handler){
           this.handler = handler;
       }

       public TypeHandler getHandler(){ return handler; }
   }

   public class TypeA {
       private Type type = TYPE_A;
       /* ... */
   }
   ```

   The handler would than be called in the following manner:

   ```
   UserInput userInput = ...;
   AbstractType data = ...;
   data.getType.getHandler().validate(data, userInput);
   ```

   The reference to the handler could also be added immediately (without the `enum` in between) as property to the `AbstractType` class, but that would mean there is a reference to a class inside the logic layer from the domain model (which kind of defeats the purpose of moving the logic to a logic layer?)

   The problem here too is that the validate method inside the TypeXHandler needs to cast the `data` argument to its subclass first before it can start validating.
2. Or I could implement some method which has a large if-then structure to get the right subclass, cast it and call the appropriate handler which implements an interface similar to the following.

   ```
   public interface TypeHandler<T extends AbstractType> {
       public validate(T data, UserInput userInput);
   }
   ```

So in both cases there is casting. In the first case there is no huge if-then structure, but the logic and domain are not separated. In the second case there is a very inflexible if-then structure.

To conclude, here is my question. Should I really avoid implementing the logic directly inside the domain? If so, is there any way to avoid the casting, the if-else structure and/or adding additional properties to the domain model (like the enum in the first "solution").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day, you're branching based on the subtype (concrete classes) since the logic to validate user input is based on those specific details contained in the subclasses.

Generics don't really help you much here since generics are based primarily on applying logic that is uniform across different types, operating on *universal logic* applied to a *common interface* that all applicable types share. Here your logic and interface varies for each subtype.

So your main choices are an inextensible solution where you're modifying central source code (like a big bunch of `ifs/elses`, a map, etc) and manually branching based on subtype, or using abstraction/dynamic polymorphism as an extensible solution which doesn't require modifying any central source code and automatically branches based on subtype.

Reflection might also be a possible route if you can afford it (it's a bit expensive at runtime) and provided it can fit to give you that universal logic you can implement centrally.

If you don't want to add this `validate` method to `AbstractType` and all of its subtypes, then you can always add another level of abstraction on top which does contain a `validate` method like `ValidatorB` which implements the `IValidator` interface and stores an object of `TypeB` as a member and applies the logic used to validate user input using `TypeB's` properties.

Comment: Thank you @Ike for the answer. I really like the paragraph with the explanation of generics! Helps me put generics into perspective. Reflection could indeed help in solving the problem, but I think it goes a bit too far just to avoid having any logic in the entities.

Comment: Do you think composition would be a good fit here? Having a `Data` class with properties `TypeA typeAcontent` and `TypeB typeBcontent` and passing the `Data` instance to the `evaluate` method of the right `IValidator` implementation? Could this get messy if the number of concrete classes increases? (it feels to me like it would be the cleanest option)

Comment: I think it depends on your extensibility needs -- how many of these `AbstractType` implementations you'll have, whether that's bound to change in the future, etc. To me the ultimate difference is whether you're going to be checking types in some central place (less extensible but might not be so bad for a small number of types) or using polymorphism.

Comment: The extensible route that is going to let you and others extend upon your solution without modifying your existing source code is going to be the polymorphic route. That is, there's no place checking for specific types. You have some virtual method that is called and the concrete class provides the logic. So if you didn't want these `AbstractType` implementations to contain logic and just focus on state, then they could become implementation details for validators which do have logic. Then you could do like: `Validator validator = new ValidatorB(...); validator->validate(userInput);`

Comment: If you do it that way, you and others can add new types of validators/abstract types in the future without changing anything that exists (hence making it the extensible solution). That includes third parties who may not have access to your source code, only the binaries like plugin authors -- they could add new validators. If you have a central place checking for types, then the only way to add new validators/types is to keep on modifying that central place each time you add a new type. So your ultimate choice lies in whether you want to check for types or stick to a polymorphic solution.

Comment: Generally it's a little better to err on that side of extensibility and polymorphism. Because if you're writing code like _"if this is type A, apply the logic for type A. If this is type B, apply the logic for type B"_, then you're often reinventing what virtual methods (anything not marked `final` in Java) already do automatically, only you're transferring the burden of manually having to maintain such code to yourself, and shutting out others from being able to extend upon your solution without modifying your existing code. With polymorphism, this is automatic and can be extended...

Comment: ... completely on the side simply by introducing new types without touching any existing code.

Comment: One problem I see with the `TypeHandler` approach you have is that it looks like that central enum might have to be changed repeatedly to add new types. That nullifies one of the primary benefits of polymorphism, which is to avoid having to change anything central repeatedly as you add new types. For extensibility, you want to be able to extend the range of solutions you have without touching any central code. A wide range of design patterns hinge upon this idea of turning an inextensible, manually-maintained branching solution into an extensible, polymorphic one.

Comment: Thank you again @Ike for your great explanation. However, the problem still remains in the case of instantiating the right validator as in `Validator validator = new ValidatorB(...);`. Since I only have the `AbstractType` reference I don't know whether to instantiate `ValidatorA` or `ValidatorB`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh sorry, I was using _"validator"_ instead of _"handler"_. Let's just call it "handler" as you have it. At some point in your code, I'm assuming you know whether to give the client a TypeA or TypeB or TypeC, etc. instance even though they reference it through the base type, `AbstractType`. If you want a polymorphic solution, the idea is to give them this Handler instead which does have an abstract `validate` method that concrete subclasses override...

Comment: ... Basically we're just using these Types as property containers at that point. The handlers use composition to store like a TypeA for a TypeHandlerA, and clients work with TypeHandler. If you cannot, for some reason, make clients work with TypeHandler instead of AbstractType, then you can use the extensible map solution that registers type mappings externally as shown in the other answer (which also has good suggestions). A map _can_ give you an extensible solution provided that you can register type associations through a public interface externally.

Answer (score 0):

I studied design patterns last week and I would like to propose my solution (it works but I'm not sure that is the smartest way to resolve your problem).

The idea of my solution is to use a factory: you give a model (in your case a JPA entity) to the factory and it gives you the correct validator for that model.

At the beginning of the program, you have to tell to the factory which is the validator class for each model class of your program through a register method.

Let's start with the implementation...

**AbstractModel.java**

```
public abstract class AbstractModel
{
    private final int commonProperty;

    protected AbstractModel(int commonProperty)
    {
        this.commonProperty = commonProperty;
    }

    public int getCommonProperty() { return commonProperty; };
}
```

In the `AbstractModel` we put all the common properties of the models.

**ModelA.java**

```
public class ModelA extends AbstractModel
{
    private final int specificProperty1;
    private final int specificProperty2;

    public ModelA(int commonProperty, int specificProperty1, int specificProperty2)
    {
        super(commonProperty);

        this.specificProperty1 = specificProperty1;
        this.specificProperty2 = specificProperty2;
    }

    public int getSpecificProperty1() { return specificProperty1; }

    public int getSpecificProperty2() { return specificProperty2; }
}
```

`ModelA` has got two specific properties.

**ModelB.java**

```
public class ModelB extends AbstractModel
{
    private final int specificProperty1;
    private final int specificProperty2;

    public ModelB(int commonProperty, int specificProperty1, int specificProperty2)
    {
        super(commonProperty);

        this.specificProperty1 = specificProperty1;
        this.specificProperty2 = specificProperty2;
    }

    public int getSpecificProperty1() { return specificProperty1; }

    public int getSpecificProperty2() { return specificProperty2; }
}
```

`ModelB` has got two specific properties too.

---

Let's say that an instance `a` of `ModelA` is valid iff

```
a.commonProperties == a.specificProperty1 + a.specificProperty2
```

and an instance `b` of `ModelB` is valid iff

```
b.commonProperties == b.specificProperty1 * b.specificProperty2
```

---

**Validator.java**

```
public interface Validator
{
    public boolean validate();
}
```

A really simple interface for the validators.

**AbstractValidator.java**

```
public abstract class AbstractValidator implements Validator
{
    private final AbstractModel toBeValidated;

    protected AbstractValidator(AbstractModel toBeValidated)
    {
        this.toBeValidated = toBeValidated;
    }

    protected AbstractModel getModel()
    {
        return toBeValidated;
    }
}
```

This is the superclass of the concrete validators that wraps the model to be validated.

**ValidatorA.java**

```
public class ValidatorA extends AbstractValidator
{
    protected ValidatorA(AbstractModel toBeValidated)
    {
        super(toBeValidated);
    }

    public boolean validate()
    {
        ModelA modelA = (ModelA) getModel();

        return modelA.getCommonProperty() == modelA.getSpecificProperty1() + modelA.getSpecificProperty2();
    }
}
```

The validator for the instances of `ModelA`.

**ValidatorB**

```
public class ValidatorB extends AbstractValidator
{
    protected ValidatorB(AbstractModel toBeValidated)
    {
        super(toBeValidated);
    }

    public boolean validate()
    {
        ModelB modelB = (ModelB) getModel();

        return modelB.getCommonProperty() == modelB.getSpecificProperty1() * modelB.getSpecificProperty2();
    }
}
```

And this is the validator for the instances of `ModelB`.

---

And finally it comes the factory!

---

**ValidatorFactory.java**

```
public class ValidatorsFactory
{
    private static ValidatorsFactory instance;
    private final HashMap<Class<? extends AbstractModel>, Class<? extends Validator>> registeredValidators;

    private ValidatorsFactory()
    {
        registeredValidators =
                new HashMap<Class<? extends AbstractModel>, Class<? extends Validator>>();
    }

    public static ValidatorsFactory getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new ValidatorsFactory();

        return instance;
    }

    public void registerValidator(
            Class<? extends AbstractModel> model,
            Class<? extends Validator> modelValidator)
    {
        registeredValidators.put(model, modelValidator);
    }

    public Validator createValidator(AbstractModel model)
    {
        Class<? extends Validator> validatorClass = registeredValidators.get(model.getClass());
        Constructor<? extends Validator> validatorConstructor = null;
        Validator validator = null;

        try
        {
            validatorConstructor = validatorClass.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class<?>[] { AbstractModel.class });
            validator = (Validator) validatorConstructor.newInstance(new Object[] { model });
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            // handle exception
        }

        return validator; 
    }
}
```

The factory is a singleton with two significant method:

1. `registerValidator` to add a new pair (modelClass, validatorClass) in the `HashMap`.
2. `createValidator` to obtain the correct validator for the specified model.

---

This is how to use this pattern:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ValidatorsFactory factory = ValidatorsFactory.getInstance();

        factory.registerValidator(ModelA.class, ValidatorA.class);
        factory.registerValidator(ModelB.class, ValidatorB.class);

        ModelA modelA = new ModelA(10, 4, 6);
        if (factory.createValidator(modelA).validate())
            System.out.println("modelA is valid");
        else
            System.out.println("modelA is not valid");

        ModelB modelB = new ModelB(10, 8, 2);
        if (factory.createValidator(modelB).validate())
            System.out.println("modelB is valid");
        else
            System.out.println("modelB is not valid");
    }
}
```

output:

```
modelA is valid [because 10 = 4 + 6]
modelB is not valid [because 10 != 8 * 2]
```

Note that the model is completely separeted from the controller and it uses only one cast from `AbstractModel` to a concrete model.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you @BlackBrain for the quick and elaborate answer. The `Map` from model to validator inside the `ValidatorsFactory` indeed solves the large if-then structure of the second "solution" I mentioned. However, we still have to cast the `AbstractModel` to its concrete subclass inside the Validator implementations. I'm wondering whether we can solve this using generics.